# Set "Start Application Pool Immediately" to true and setting username password when creating app pool with power shell

Tags: powershell, iis-8

I am creating app pools via power shell script.

1. Even after looking around i couldn't find how to set the "Start Application Pool immediately" to true. How can i do this?
2. Also, if the userName/password are provided then i want to set it otherwise it should be Application Pool Identity. Am i doing it correctly?

Here is the function

```
Function Create-AppPools($appPoolName, $appPoolDotNetVersion, $managedPipelineMode, $startMode, $userName, $password) {
    if(!$appPoolName){
        return;
    }

    Write-Host " "

    #navigate to the app pools root
    cd IIS:\AppPools\

    #check if the app pool exists
    if (!(Test-Path $appPoolName -pathType container))
    {
        Write-Host "`t Creating AppPool: " + $appPoolName
        #create the app pool
        $appPool = New-Item $appPoolName
        if($appPoolDotNetVersion){
            $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $appPoolDotNetVersion
        }
        if(@managedPipelineMode){
            $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value $managedPipelineMode
        }
        if($startMode){
            $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "startMode" -Value $startMode
        }
        if($userName -and $password){
            $apppool | Set-ItemProperty -Name processmodel -value @{userName = $userName;password=$password;identitytype=3}
        }
        else{
            $apppool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "ProcessModel.IdentityType" -value  3
        }
        Write-Host "`t`t AppPool: " + $appPoolName + " created successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "`t AppPool " + $appPoolName + " already exists" -ForegroundColor Blue
    }
}
```

Update 1: 
Check [github](https://github.com/tahirjadoon/2020-IIS-Tasks-App-Pools-Sites) for sample scripts after i got my question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in your fourth `if()`.
Other than that your code works as expected.

- It starts the application pool immediately. This can be verified from the CLI and IIS Management GUI.
- If the user/password params are correct in that the user exists and the password is accurate, the pool's identity will be set to those params. This can be verified in the IIS Management GUI.

I'd recommend specifying the modules your code depends on via a `#Requires` statement.

```bsh
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
#Requires -Modules WebAdministration

Function Create-AppPools(
    $appPoolName = "TestPool2", 
    $appPoolDotNetVersion = "v4.0", 
    $managedPipelineMode = "Integrated", 
    $startMode = "OnDemand", 
    $userName, 
    $password
) {
    if (!$appPoolName) {
        return;
    }

    Write-Host " "

    #navigate to the app pools root
    cd IIS:\AppPools\

    #check if the app pool exists
    if (!(Test-Path $appPoolName -pathType container)) {
        Write-Host "`t Creating AppPool: " + $appPoolName
        #create the app pool
        $appPool = New-Item $appPoolName
        if ($appPoolDotNetVersion) {
            $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $appPoolDotNetVersion
        }
        if ($managedPipelineMode) {
            $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value $managedPipelineMode
        }
        if ($startMode) {
            $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "startMode" -Value $startMode
        }
        if ($userName -and $password) {
            $apppool | Set-ItemProperty -Name processmodel -value @{userName = $userName; password = $password; identitytype = 3 }
        }
        else {
            $apppool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "ProcessModel.IdentityType" -value  3
        }
        Write-Host "`t`t AppPool: " + $appPoolName + " created successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "`t AppPool " + $appPoolName + " already exists" -ForegroundColor Blue
    }
}

Create-AppPools
```

Comment: Thanks @derekbaker! do you know how easy can i set .netClrVersion to No Managed Code?

Comment: @learning... I think you'd set your `$appPoolDotNetVersion` param to `$null`. To determine this, I ran the following code after creating a pool with that setting: `Import-Module IISAdministration; Get-IISAppPool | Select-Object -Property *`. When I do that, it appears empty.

Comment: For the dotNetVersion "No Managed Code", have to pass in the "No Managed Code" string. So here is the info `appPoolDotNetVersion = v2.0 | v4.0 | No Managed Code` and `appPoolManagedPipelineMode = Classic | Integrated` and `appPoolStartMode = OnDemand | AlwaysRunning`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't fully address the headline question:

> How do I set the AppPool checkbox setting "Start application pool immediately"?"

As documented over here: https://serverfault.com/questions/828200/difference-between-start-application-pool-immediately-and-start-mode-alwaysrun, the checkbox for "Start application pool immediately" on 'Basic Settings' is entirely unrelated to the "StartMode" setting in 'Advanced Settings'. It appears that IIS refers to the checkbox as the `autoStart` setting of the AppPool.

The script you provided actively sets the `StartMode`, but is leaves `autoStart` at its default value. As it happens the default value for both `New-WebAppPool` and `New-Item`(when called in an IIS drive) is `autoStart = "true"`, so it happens to be what you originally wanted already. :)

But if you want to set it to false, or have a script that actively sets the value on an existing App Pool with unknown state, then you do that like this:

```
IIS:\> $newAppPool = New-WebAppPool -Name "NewAppPool"
IIS:\> $newAppPool.autoStart = "false"
IIS:\> $newAppPool | Set-Item
IIS:\> # ... later ....
IIS:\> cd IIS:/AppPools
IIS:\> $appPoolIJustCreated = Get-Item "NewAppPool"
IIS:\> $appPoolIJustCreated.autoStart = "true"
IIS:\> $appPoolIJustCreated | Set-Item
```

*Warning: When creating an AppPool on cmd line, whilst IIS is open beside it. You have to refresh the  node of the tree to see the new Pool ... not the 'ApplicationPools' node.*
Documentation:

- [Default value is true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/applicationpooldefaults/#configuration).
- [How to set the value during creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/new-webapppool?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-2-create-an-iis-application-pool-and-set-autostart).
- [How to set the value on an existing Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611425/enable-auto-start-property-in-iis-8-application-pool-for-multiple-servers)